# How to draw edges of a graph with different colors according to their weights with neovis.js (Neo4j)?

Tags: neo4j, vis.js

I have a graph with weighted edges in Neo4j. I visualized it with neovis.js library as shown in the attached figure. Currently, all edges have same color. In the next step I need to assign colors to edges such that every group (Cluster or Community) of edges has a different color based on a predefined property of the edges (the property is defined for edges not vertices).

My graph node and relationship are stored as follows:

Node: Vertex (index, name), Ex: (42, "Vertex 23")

Relationship: EDGE (index, count, group), Ex: (12, 42, 0), (24, 230, 1)

(:Vertex)-[:EDGE]->(:Vertex)

Here is my code for creating the graph:

```
<html>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/master/dist/neovis.js"></script>
    <script>
        function draw() {
            var config = {
                container_id: "viz",
                server_url: "bolt://localhost:7687",
                server_user: "***",
                server_password: "***",
                labels: {
                    "Vertex": {
                        caption: "name"
                    }
                },
                relationships: {
                    "EDGE": {
                        caption: false,
                        thickness: "count"
                    }                   
                },
                initial_cypher: "MATCH p=()-[:RELATIONSHIP]->() RETURN p"
            }
            var viz = new NeoVis.default(config);
            viz.render();
        }
    </script>
    <body onload="draw()">
        <div id="viz"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It would be good if I can map a specific color to each group as well.
Let's say group is a binary property, so I want something like this:

```
...
relationships: {
                    "EDGE": {
                        caption: false,
                        thickness: "count"
                        color: "group" {0: red, 1: green}
                    }                   
                },
...
```

[image: The visualized weighted graph by neovis.js]

Comment: Please provide sample data for testing and your attempt.

Comment: Sure, I added my code and the properties of nodes and relations that I have. @stdob--

Comment: The problem is that the `neovis.js` library does not provide an easy way to do this. So it is easier to use together `vis.js network` (http://visjs.org/docs/network/) and `neo4j-javascript-driver` (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver) without using this library.